# JavaScript RegExp referencing another RegExp (syntax error)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to match any text that references a somewhat complicated regex I've defined that looks like:

```
var oneRx = /Seite((\S+)\s+\S.*?)(?=\s*\2)/;
```

The text I want should immediately follow (but not include) oneRx, and end in one or more digits with one or more spaces to the left and right of these digits.

```
var twoRx = new RegExp('(?<=' + oneRx + ')' + '.+\s+\d{1,}\s+$');
```

For instance, I'd like to take the string:

```
SeiteSGP0136.1 3SE7120 3SE7120-1BF00 SGP0137.1 3SE7140 3SE7140-1CD00 SGP0138.1 3SE7150 3SE7150-1BH00 SGP0136.1 SGP0136.1 One 1 SGP0136.1 Two 3
```

And return

```
SGP0136.1 SGP0136.1 One 1 SGP0136.1 Two 3
```

I think the second part of the regex is fine, but I can't figure out how to define the first without creating a syntax error.

How should I reference `oneRx` in `twoRx`?

Comment: Use *double escapes in constructor notation*. Besdies, JS does not support lookbehind. Please provide a string for a test with expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not support lookbehinds. What you can do is using capturing groups instead :

```js
var oneRx = 'Seite((\\S+)\\s+\\S.*?)(?=\\s*\\2)';  

var twoRx = new RegExp(oneRx + '(.+\\s+\\d+\\s+)$');

var str = 'SeiteSGP0136.1 3SE7120 3SE7120-1BF00 SGP0137.1 3SE7140 3SE7140-1CD00 SGP0138.1 3SE7150 3SE7150-1BH00 SGP0136.1 SGP0136.1 One 1 SGP0136.1 Two 3 ';

var match = str.match(twoRx);
console.log(match[3]);
```

**Important :**
Acces what your looking for with `match[3]` (capturing group 3)
You have to escape *escape characters* in your string when you create regex string in javascript.

Comment: Well.. I'm 7 min late ^^

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

JS regex engine does not support a lookbehind. Also, you should use `.source` *RegExp* property to combine regex patterns in a constructor notation where escaping backslashes must be doubled to denote literal backslashes.

```js
var oneRx = /Seite((\S+)\s+\S.*?)(?=\s*\2)/;
var twoRx = new RegExp(oneRx.source + '(.+\\s+\\d+\\s+)$');
var s = "SeiteSGP0136.1 3SE7120 3SE7120-1BF00 SGP0137.1 3SE7140 3SE7140-1CD00 SGP0138.1 3SE7150 3SE7150-1BH00 SGP0136.1 SGP0136.1 One 1 SGP0136.1 Two 3 ";
var res = (m = s.match(twoRx)) ? m[3].trim() : "";
console.log(res);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PsJSGo/1/).

You seem to need the value captured with `.+\s+\d+\s+` pattern, so all you need is to wrap that part of the pattern with capturing parentheses.

Note that `m[3].trim()` trims the value from redundant whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  The match wasn't what I wanted though, see my edit with expected match.

Comment: I just noticed. You seem to need the value captured with `.+\\s+\\d+\\s+` pattern, so all you need is to wrap that part of the pattern with a capturing group. Next time, please indicate what your string and expected match look like to avoid answer sniping.